# Use IOptions Pattern for Reading Configuration Settings from Azure Key Vault and Azure App Configuration in a .NET 7 Microservices Application

Tags: c#, azure-keyvault, .net-7.0, azure-app-configuration

I'm working on a .NET 7 microservices-based application, and I need to manage configuration settings from both Azure Key Vault and Azure App Configuration. To maintain a consistent and clean way of accessing these settings throughout my application, I want to implement the IOptions pattern.

Specifically, I'm looking for guidance on how to set up and use IOptions to read configuration settings from both Azure Key Vault and Azure App Configuration seamlessly. If you have any code samples or references that demonstrate how to achieve this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Here are some additional details:

The application uses .NET 7.
I'm currently using the Azure.Extensions.AspNetCore.Configuration package to read settings from Azure App Configuration.
I'm also using the Azure.Identity package for authenticating with Azure services.
Can anyone provide a step-by-step guide or point me in the right direction with code samples and relevant documentation, it would be a huge help.

Can anyone please help me here by providing their guidance

Comment: There are loads of guides online showing how to do this, what is it about them that you don't like?

Comment: Please share the code which you have tried. Your `Program.cs` and `appsettings.json` file.

Comment: Thanks @DavidG for your reply. I see lots of examples in context to anything that is maintained in application.settings.json file. The challenge here I am seeing is how to leverage IOptions pattern irrespective of the facts the source of data is from AzureKeyVault or AzureAppConfigitation

Comment: Those things all plug into the standard `IConfiguration`, did you try to use them yet?

Comment: @DavidG - I have used it with configuration without any issues but wanted to bring this usage in case of anything that is read from AzureKeyVault also

Comment: It's the same thing, did you try it? You can even plug KeyVaul directly into Azure App Config service

Answer (score 2):

App configuration supports key vault references so you could manage secrets from app configuration and only deals with app configuration from your application:

- [Add a Key Vault reference to App Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/use-key-vault-references-dotnet-core?tabs=core6x#add-a-key-vault-reference-to-app-configuration)